# Java Reflection: (Type) field.get(object) - unchecked cast

Tags: java, reflection, unchecked-cast

Following code retrieves the value of a field using the Reflection API.
As you can see in the provided image, this generates an *unchecked cast* warning.
The warning can be suppressed using *@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")*. I was wondering if there is an alternative to this though?

Update: KeyType is a generic. So *KeyType.class.cast(object);* wouldn't work due to type erasure.

```
private K getId(Field idField, V o) {
    K id = null;
    try {
        idField.setAccessible(true);
        id = (K) idField.get(o);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {
        /* This never occurs since we have set the field accessible */
    }
    return id;
}
```

[image: Unchecked cast warning]

---

Solution:
Seems like the *SuppressWarnings* annotation IS the way to go here.. thanks for your time guys.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Wrap the gotten value into KeyType.class.cast(Object obj)

Comment: KeyType is a generic. Due to type erasure this won't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't see that it is generic.

Comment: That is kind of important information, which should be in question... Please edit you post and include this info there.

Comment: Also to avoid such confusion when reading code later we generally use one letter names for generic types like `K` for key type, `V` for value type and so on.

Comment: Renamed them, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Class method cast doesn't require the @SupressWarnigns  even though it still can throw ClassCastException.

```
KeyType keyType = KeyType.class.cast( idField.get(o) );
```

You can - since at that location you should know the generic paramter(s) - proceed like this:

```
private static class ListInteger extends ArrayList<Integer>{}

Object obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ListInteger test = ListInteger.class.cast(obj);
```

Once you have an object of class KeyType you can, of course,

```
KeyType keyTypeX = ...; // not null

KeyType keyType = keyTypeX.getClass().cast( obj );
```

There are alternatives, although the @SuppressWarnings isn't so bad - try to limit it to an declaration+assignment, don't put it on the method.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that KeyType is a generic. Due to type erasure your solution won't work.
I'm considering passing the KeyType's class type to the constructor of this class though.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `get` method of Field is

```
public Object get(Object obj) { 
 ...
}
```

Since it is not generic, the return type is Object, you cannot enforce any error to appear at **compile-time**.

If you are sure that the type of the value is `ValueType` all the time, then add documentation to the method, saying the type will be always ValueType and use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").